UraniumUI RadioButton styling
I'm replicating example from official UraniumUI documentation (link), the radio buttons with reversed label position, which should look like this:
Uranium UI example

Unfortunately it doesn't look like example at all. It looks like this instead:
The actual result

Here is my main page code which contains the radio buttons:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<uranium:UraniumContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MAUIUraniumTest.MainPage"
             xmlns:uranium="http://schemas.enisn-projects.io/dotnet/maui/uraniumui"
             xmlns:material="http://schemas.enisn-projects.io/dotnet/maui/uraniumui/material">
    <StackLayout Margin="20">
        <material:RadioButtonGroupView>
            <material:RadioButton Text="Option 1" LabelPosition="Before" />
            <material:RadioButton Text="Option 2" LabelPosition="Before" />
            <material:RadioButton Text="Option 3 (Disabled)" IsDisabled="True" LabelPosition="Before" />
            <material:RadioButton Text="Option 4 (Disabled)" IsDisabled="True" IsChecked="True" LabelPosition="Before" />
        </material:RadioButtonGroupView>
    </StackLayout>
</uranium:UraniumContentPage>

Code behind:
public partial class MainPage : UraniumContentPage
{
    int count = 0;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

App.xaml:
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8" ?>
<Application xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MAUIUraniumTest"
             xmlns:material="http://schemas.enisn-projects.io/dotnet/maui/uraniumui/material"
             x:Class="MAUIUraniumTest.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary x:Name="appColors" Source="Resources/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary x:Name="appStyles" Source="Resources/Styles/Styles.xaml" />

                <material:StyleResource ColorsOverride="{x:Reference appColors}" BasedOn="{x:Reference appStyles}" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>

And MauiProgram.cs:
    public static class MauiProgram
    {
        public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
        {
            var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
            builder
                .UseMauiApp<App>()
                .UseUraniumUI()
                .UseUraniumUIMaterial()
                .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
                {
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
                });

#if DEBUG
            builder.Logging.AddDebug();
#endif

            return builder.Build();
        }
    }

I'm unsure what to do. Program compiles and launches properly, and everything is done according to the official documentation.

You can also  refer to the source code about UraniumUI RadioButton: UraniumUI/src/UraniumUI.Material/Controls
/RadioButton.cs | InputKit.Shared.Controls.RadioButton

I can reproduce your question, and it can be achieved by setting ColumnSpacing:
<StackLayout Margin="20">
   <material:RadioButtonGroupView>
       <material:RadioButton Text="Option 1" LabelPosition="Before" ColumnSpacing="260"/>
       <material:RadioButton Text="Option 2" LabelPosition="Before" ColumnSpacing="260"/>
       <material:RadioButton Text="Option 3 (Disabled)" IsDisabled="True" LabelPosition="Before" ColumnSpacing="194"/>
       <material:RadioButton Text="Option 4 (Disabled)" IsDisabled="True" IsChecked="True" LabelPosition="Before" ColumnSpacing="194"/>
   </material:RadioButtonGroupView>
</StackLayout>

Here is the effect.

It doesn't seem like perfect solution since you would have to come up with an algorithm to calculate column spacing, but I'm not sure if there is any other way so I will mark it as solution.

Seems it was broken by the PR https://github.com/enisn/Xamarin.Forms.InputKit/pull/372
